# An Exception was thrown while handling: Wrong Version

Tags: symfony, routes

i want to to create user with name = {user}, but an execption lanched "An Exception was thrown while handling: Wrong Version"

```
createSale:
    path:      /user/{user}/create/
    defaults:  { _controller: AppBundle:Controller:create}
    methods:  [PUT]
    requirements:
        user:  .{1,60}
```

Comment: which version you are talking about?

Comment: really i don't know :/

Comment: can you post the stack trace of the error